# Split List of ids in to integer and string?

Tags: shell-scripting

I am having a list of ids (total 2 lakh), I want to write a shell script to split the ids (string and integer) using shell script . Example given below :

`IDlist.txt`:

```
   | LT345   |
   | R567    |
   | LT9     |
   | MRTD002 |
   | MK53    |
   | RR567   |
```

I have extracted the ids from IDlist.txt with the following script.

```
awk '{print $2}' IDlist.txt > newId_list.txt
```

`newId_list.txt`:

```
LT345   
R567    
LT9     
MRTD002 
MK53    
RR567
```

How can I split the newId_list.txt ids as given below ?

`result_string.txt`:

```
LT
R
LT
MRTD
MK
RR
```

`result_integer.txt`:

```
345
567
9
002
53
567
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/grep) with the `-o` option to match certain characters and only output those. For example:

```
% grep -E -o '[A-Z]+' newId_list.txt
LT
R
LT
MRTD
MK
RR

% grep -E -o '[0-9]+' newId_list.txt
345
567
9
002
53
567
```

This could even be run on the orginial `IDlist.txt` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `tr` to remove unneeded symbols:

```
tr -d \|\ [:alpha:] < idlist.txt                                                                                                                                                                                 
345
567
9
002
53
567

tr -d \|\ [:digit:] < idlist.txt 
LT
R
LT
MRTD
MK
RR
```